# input.getaxis for 3d in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I would like to convert my 2D script into a 3D script, but am running into a road block when trying to program the z axis for the 3D script. I need to know how to change `input.getaxis("Horizontal")` to something that includes the z axis.

Comment: You need to post the original 2D script then the 3D scripting that doesn't work. You also should explain the exact problem you are having with that 3D code.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the InputManager in Unity via `Edit -> Project Settings -> Input`.

There you can define a new Axis for your likes and then access it as you are used to using `Input.GetAxis()`.